# Show guest name next room no. in multiple dates

Tags: excel-365

I'm trying to find out how to show guest name againts room no. in the days he is staying in the hotel room

| Guest Name | #Room | Date-In | Date-Out | #Nights |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sara | 203 | 12/11/2022 | 14/11/2022 | 2 |
| Miton | 204 | 13/11/2022 | 16/11/2022 | 3 |
| Andrea | 202 | 13/11/2022 | 15/11/2022 | 2 |
| Maite | 205 | 14/11/2022 | 15/11/2022 | 1 |
| Darzen | 206 | 15/11/2022 | 17/11/2022 | 2 |
| Eshtakish | 208 | 16/11/2022 | 17/11/2022 | 1 |

New Sheet has to look like this:

| Date | 202 | 203 | 204 | 205 | 206 | 208 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12/11/2022 |  | Sara |  |  |  |  |
| 13/11/2022 | Andrea | Sara | Miton |  |  |  |
| 14/11/2022 | Andrea |  | Miton | Maite |  |  |
| 15/11/2022 |  |  | Miton |  | Darzen |  |
| 16/11/2022 |  |  |  |  | Darzen | Eshtakish |
| 17/11/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Could anyone help?

I tried this formala but it shows guest name only in the first day, whereas, I need to show guest name in all days he booked.

```
INDEX('Daily Record'!$B$3:$B$308,MATCH($A$2:$A$82&B$1,'Daily Record'!$I$3:$I$308&'Daily Record'!$F$3:$F$308,0)
```